# Prevent Spotify using 3G on iPhone

Tags: iphone, spotify

On the Spotify iPhone app, there is a manual setting to turn offline mode on or off. Ideally there would be a feature that automatically switches to offline mode as soon as a wifi connection is dropped, and switches back to online mode when connected again. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Spotify.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off cellular data per app. Go to `Settings` -> `Cellular` and scroll to the bottom, tap to turn off cellular data for an app.

[image: Image from Apple page]